# Do I lose data if I change from INT to TINYINT

Tags: mysql, datatypes, integer

I have a database (Engine `InnoDB`) that was setup by someone else. I noticed that one column contains data between 1 and 107 at this moment, and it is highly unlikely to further increase much.

As it is currently set up as `INT` my idea was to change type to `TINYINT unsigned`.

Can I just do that without losing data? What would be the most efficient way to go about it?

I am still rather new to databases, getting my hands dirty at the moment and learning all about data types and performance, etc. Looks like my precursor hasn't done such a good job... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tiny int will save you space. Here are their storage:

tinyint: 1 byte
smallint: 2 bytes
int: 4 bytes

From MySQL official website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html

Keep in mind a tinyint has a range up to 255. If there is a chance you may go over, I would use smallint or int

You can alter the column in sql and not lose data:

```
    alter table MyTable alter column MyColumn tinyint --(null|not null)
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I already knew the details in your answer (size, range, how to do it) but it is good to know there won't be data loss. That was the main question.

Comment: @koljanep np. If you happen to have data that can't be converted to a tinyint, sql will throw an error and no data will be lost either way.

Comment: @koljanep Several addendums. In order to avoid mistakes, make sure you are using `ENGINE=Innodb` and `sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'`, so you can rollback in case of an unexpected problem. I recommend using `tinyint unsigned` as that will give you the (0,255) range. Only starting with 5.6 can the datatype be changed online, otherwise write transactions for that table may fail while the `ALTER` is ongoing.

Comment: Warning, this will lock your table, at least on version 5.6! See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html